Why duality formula holds for L^2
If $f, g \in L^2$, how to show  $ \int f. \hat{g} = \int \hat{f}.g $. This fourier transform is defined by extending the definition for space of schwartz function( using bounded linear extension theorem). I am not able to use that above holds for schwartz function and use density to prove for $L^2$.
At first, I will write integral using inner product and forgetting the conjugate to make life easy.
Also suppose that at first g is Schwartz function and f is $L^2$, then
$\langle f, \hat{g} \rangle - \langle \hat{f}, g \rangle = \langle f, \hat{g} \rangle - \langle f_{n}, \hat{g} \rangle + \langle f_{n}, \hat{g} \rangle - \langle \hat{f}, g \rangle $ where $f_{n}$ is sequence of schwartz function that converges to $f$, in expression, $\langle f_{n}, \hat{g} \rangle $, we can apply say $\langle f_{n}, \hat{g} \rangle= \langle \hat{f_{n}}, g \rangle $ and we get true this case.
Oh, I think it can solve second case as well. Can someone verify.

Where do you have problems in the proof? Can you show us your attempt?

yes i will add something now.

I think it works. can you check @LL3.14
